# Is there still no way to remove AirDrop from the sharing options?

Tags: ios, airdrop

With iOS 17 AirDrop seems to still be impossible to delete from, or place later in the list of, sharing options. Is there a behind the scenes way to get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: I would say that from the lack of a removal button and the "move an item up and down target" that Apple is telling you that it can't be moved or removed. I imagine Apple believes that Airdrop is an essential OS service, and because of that, has disallowed its removal.

Comment: @SteveChambers I suspect you're right. Fortunately these are the sorts of restrictions on choice an degradation of UX that come up in antitrust cases. (Yes, I know, but one cane hope!)